# How to write type converter for nested object in android

Tags: android, android-room

I tried to write type converter for following object but its not working.

```
    data class GlobalStatus(
            val ai: UseCaseStatus,
            var user: UseCaseStatus,
            val global: UseCaseStatus
        )
    
enum class UseCaseStatus(val text: Int) {
    UNKNOWN(R.string.status_unknown)
}
    
    class GlobalStatusTypeConverter {
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromString(useCaseDetails: String?): GlobalStatus? {
            return Gson().fromJson(useCaseDetails, GlobalStatus::class.java)
        }
    
        @TypeConverter
        fun toString(useCaseDetails: GlobalStatus?): String? {
            return Gson().toJson(useCaseDetails)
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.